# dune-ocaml : No implementations provided for the following modules:

Tags: ocaml, dune

I tried to compile an OCaml code with Dune but got the following error:

```
Error: No implementations provided for the following modules:
CallccBp referenced from bin/.CallccTest.eobjs/native/dune__exe__CallccTest.cmx
```

by executing the command : `$ dune build`

My project hierarchy is as follows:

```
callcc/

    bin/

      callccTest.ml

      dune
        [

         (executable

         (name callccTest)

         (libraries CallccBp))

        ]
   lib/
      CallccBp.mli

      dune
       [

       (library

       (name CallccBp)

       (modules_without_implementation CallccBp))
        ]

   test/

    callccTest.ml

     dune [
      (test
       (name callccTest))
       ]

callcc.opam

dune-project
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the discussion you had with octachron, let's start from the basics:

`my_module.mli`

> File where you declare the signatures of your values, modules etc. Not mandatory, I'd advise not using them if you start with OCaml

`my_module.ml`

> File where you implement your values, modules etc. Mandatory since these are the files that make your program run

Let's see this with a toy project:

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── dune
         (executable
          (name main)
         )
│   └── main.ml
├── dune-project
├── lib
│   ├── dune
         (library
          (name my_module)
         )
│   └── my_module.ml
└── program.opam
```

If I want to use values from `my_module` in `bin/main.ml`, I have to:

- have values in `my_module.ml`
- add the `(libraries my_module)` stanza in my `bin/dune` file
- use these values with `My_module.<name_of_value>`

So this looks like:

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── dune
         (executable
          (name main)
          (libraries my_module)
         )
│   └── main.ml
         let () =
           let b = My_module.incr 3 in
           Printf.printf "%d\n" b
├── dune-project
├── lib
│   ├── dune
│   └── my_module.ml
         let incr a = a + 1
└── program.opam
```

Now, let's go back to your hierarchy:

```
callcc/
    bin/
      callccTest.ml
      dune
        [
         (executable
         (name callccTest)
         (libraries CallccBp))
        ]
   lib/
      CallccBp.mli
      dune
       [
       (library
       (name CallccBp)
       (modules_without_implementation CallccBp))
        ]
   test/
    callccTest.ml
     dune [
      (test
       (name callccTest))
       ]
callcc.opam
dune-project
```

Everything looks fine except from the fact that `CallccBp.mli` is just an interface, not an implementation. As a starter you could remove this file, create `CallccBp.ml` filled with these two functions:

`CallccBp.ml`

```ml
let callcc = failwith "TODO"
let throw = failwith "TODO"
```

If you compile, dune should not complain and now all you'll have to do will be to provide a much useful implementation than `failwith "TODO"`

---

And if we go back to our toy project, to see why you'd want to have an mli file:

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── dune
         (executable
          (name main)
          (libraries my_module)
         )
│   └── main.ml
         let () =
           let b = My_module.incr 3 in
           Printf.printf "%d\n" b
├── dune-project
├── lib
│   ├── dune
│   └── my_module.ml
         let dummy _ = failwith "USELESS"
         let incr a = a + 1
│   └── my_module.mli
         val incr : int -> int
         (** [incr d] will return [d] incremented by 1. Highly efficient. Trust me. *)
└── program.opam
```

I'll be able to use `My_module.incr` in `bin/main.ml` but not `My_module.dummy` because it is not shown by the `mli` file and thus not accessible outside of `my_module.ml`. And as a bonus, `my_module.mli` file is the entry point for a library user who doesn't want to know how it is implemented but just wants to use it knowing the available values, their types and, often, what they do from the comment.

---

The `modules_without_implementation` stanza is for `mli` files that don't need implementations, namely, type declarations files so modules looking like this:

`AST.mli`

```
type ('a, 'b) res = Ok of 'a | Error of 'b
type num = Int of int | Float of float
type person = {id : int; name : string; age : num}
```

And you can use them in another file like this:

`file.ml`

```ml
type t = {player1 : AST.person; player2 : AST.person}

let whos_older p1 p2 =
  Printf.printf "%s is older\n"
    (if p1.AST.age > p2.AST.age then p1.name else p2.name)
```

But that's not really useful when starting since, once again, I'd advise not touching `mli` files in the beginning

Comment: Thank you very much for all these explanations.

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, don't forget to accept it @MMYMMY

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: There's a checkmark next to the two arrows surrounding the 0 that you can click on

Answer (score 0):

The error message is complaining that there is no implementation (aka no ml file) for the module `CallccBp`. Without knowing the content of `CallccBp`, it is probable that this module contain either an exception or an extension constructor declaration (or any other kind of runtime components). Your first fix should be to add a `callccBp.ml` file and remove the `(module_without_implementation ...)` line.

Comment: the module is of type signature .mli
type 'a cont val callcc: ('a cont -> 'a) -> 'a val throw: 'a cont -> 'a -> 'b

and I use it in callccTest.ml
open CallccBp.

Comment: Then it is not possible to not have an implementation file, since the module contains two runtime values `callcc` and `throw`.

Comment: Without the deposit
(modules_without_implementation callccBp)

I have the following error: File “lib/dune”, line 1, characters 0-26:
1 | (library
2 | (name CallccBp))
Error: Some modules don’t have an implementation.
You need to add the following field to this stanza:

(modules_without_implementation callccBp)

Comment: Indeed, you need to add an implementation for your `callcc` and `throw` functions in a `callccBp.ml` file.

Comment: How can I add:

type 'a cont
val callcc: ('a cont -> 'a) -> 'a
val throw: 'a cont -> 'a -> 'b

on a  .ml file without problem ?

Comment: You have to write the implementation of those functions. (And `val ...` is only valid in mli file).

Comment: I wrote it like:
let callcc = ('a cont -> 'a) -> 'a

let throw = 'a cont -> 'a -> 'b

But I have the error:

File "bin/CallCCTest.ml", line 3, characters 14-15:
3 | let callcc = ('a cont -> 'a) -> 'a
                  ^
Error: Syntax error: expected operator.

There is a solution with                                                                                       
 module type ... = sig
end ?

Comment: There is no solution with module types. At some point you have to write down an implementation. `let callcc = ('a cont -> 'a)` is not valid OCaml code.